# Macbook Pro Retina 13,3" tingling/buzzing sensation

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, charging, display

Okay, so YESTERDAY i bought my (super very wow expensive) Macbook Pro Retina 13,3". Huge investment for me.
Yesterday night i tried charging i for the first time, and it started tingling against the palms of my hands whenever i like moved it across the under-keyboard area. I've read a lot about it, and i've read that it's normal, and that i have to use a three plug charger - the problem is that in Denmark we dont use three plug chargers, so i really dont know what to do! I just can't believe that i've saved so many money for so long, and that I experience problems after less than 12 hours.. ugh.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: Haha i just asked my mom and it's not that common, we normally just use two plugs, but i guess i could be like a transformer.

Answer (score 1):

In Denmark you have 2 types of wall plug.

Both have ground connection.

The left one is standard European type and it has two ground connection showing as springs. Your Apple plug should just fit in that one.

I am assuming the socket it is actually connected to the ground in your place.

[image]

Comment: Yes, and it's when i use the left one it happens. But my plug isn't round its flat like normal chargers in Europe. But i got an extension cord with the normal charger, which ends as a three plug thing - so i'll try that out! The weirdest part is that i'm using my old white MacBook right now, which doesn't give me that same tingling sensation - only when i touch the round part going into the computer. Maybe it could have something to do with the aluminum ''shell''?

Comment: are you standing or sitting on a tile floor or wooden floor? If you try not to touch any ground surfaces around you then there should be no tingling.